# Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) Incompatible execution data for class

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

this is the sonar additional properties configured in jenkins coverage job:

> -Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_unit.exec
>    -Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
>    -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
>    -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_it.exec

i am getting the error below on jenkins :

> Jenkins Log: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project aaaa-parent: Incompatible execution data for
>   class xxxxxxxxxxxxx with id 4050af3ab5fc5456. -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project xxxxx: Incompatible execution data for class
>   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with id 4050af3ab5fc5456.  at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

the strange thing is that, if i set the reportPath and itReportPath the same, no matter merged_unit.exec or merged_it.exec, the sonar analysis goes well
but if i set what it should be , the error comes up .

the project is a muti-modules one, so i use the xml below to merge (i only put one module first for testing)

```
<target name="merge_unit_exec">
                <jacoco:merge destfile="/home/qatest/test-script/aaa/unittest/report/merged_unit.exec">
                        <fileset dir="/home/qatest/jenkins/workspace/aaaa/aaa/target" includes="*.exec" />
                </jacoco:merge>
</target>
```

it blocks me 2days, really appreciate for your great help., thank you

Answer (score 1):

`Incompatible execution data for class` means that execution data contains exact same class twice, but with a different number of probes.

So check that you use exact same latest JaCoCo version everywhere. Check that you don't have stale exec files to which you append data, while they were created with another version of JaCoCo. Check that you don't have non-graceful termination of JVM that might result in incomplete corrupted exec files.

Check similar questions about same exception in [“IllegalStateException: Incompatible execution data for class in…” exception from Jacoco when run for an existing ear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259246/illegalstateexception-incompatible-execution-data-for-class-in-exception-fro) and https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/95

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i tried to unified the jacoco version, but t doesn't work.  and finally i solved this error only by changing the config order , like below    `` Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_unit.exec Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_it.exec
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports``

Answer (score 0):

```
-Dsonar.jacoco.reportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_unit.exec
-Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=${WORKSPACE}/merged_it.exec
-Dsonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco
-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
```

i found the solution above, but who can give a reasonable answer of that